# Do CUDA threads execute in lockstep for O(n) operations?

Tags: cuda

The CUDA programming guide has the following to say:

> A warp executes **one common instruction at a time**, so full efficiency is realized when all 32 threads of a warp agree on their execution path. If threads of a warp diverge via a data-dependent conditional branch, the warp serially executes each branch path taken, disabling threads that are not on that path, and when all paths complete, the threads converge back to the same execution path.

I'm thinking lockstep because of **one common instruction at a time**.

1. So what happens in the case where there is no branching and each thread needs to compute an O(n) operation?
2. Won't some threads in the warp complete before others if the value of the data they operate on is smaller?
3. If some threads do complete before others do they remain idle until the others complete?

Comment: Guide refers to concrete machine instructions which are O(1) (at least in theory). Your O(n) operation consists of machine instructions. In order to threads in a warp finish before others you will need to feed them with different data. This is only possible with a branch (unless I am wrong here, and you have a counterexample).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to find out; will threads in a warp finish before others if they are fed with different data?

Comment: My point is: you cannot feed different stuff without a branch (i.e. assumption in (1) is wrong). And in case of branching, each path is of the same length and is serialized. So threads finish at the same time anyway.

Comment: Each thread performs N operations where N is equal to thread's global ID. Won't this suffice as each thread having its own data? I may be conceptually confused about something; so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "performs N operations" is a loop. Non-infinite loops contain stop conditions (`i < thread_id` in this case). Conditions are branches.

Comment: Quite right! I completely overlooked stop condition as a branch. Therefore it is possible for threads in a warp to complete before others. Thanks. If you post this as the answer I'd happily mark it as accepted.

Comment: It might be easier to explain this way: Threads in a warp are not real threads. They cannot run independent instructions. Enormous amounts of "CUDA cores" in Nvidia architectures is not a miracle, but a work of their marketing department. In reality, "warp" is just another fancy name for "vector", like vector in SSE, AVX or NEON instruction sets on CPUs. All vector instructions are indivisible and run on entire vector. Input is a vector, output is a vector. No branches are possible inside. Shorter vectors are just padded longer vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each single instruction in a warp is performed in a lockstep. The next instruction can be fetched only when the previous one has completed.
If an instruction needs a different amount of time for different threads (e.g. one thread loaded data from cache, while the other waits for global memory reads), then all threads have to wait.

That being said, I am not aware of any single instruction having a complexity `O(n)`. What you are probably referring to is a loop of size `n` being executed by each of the threads in a warp. Loop, same as any other control flow construct, has a conditional jump. Threads that exit the loop early become masked and wait for the threads still in the loop. When all threads signal that they want to exit, they converge, and the following operations are once again performed in a perfect sync.

---

Update: As @knedlsepp points out (thank you!) since Volta this is not true. The GPU may split a warp into smaller pieces and run those independently, thus breaking the lockstep. You shouldn't assume too much, but warp synchronisation primities may help.

In practice, GPU will still try to run whole warp in lock step when possible, as this is most efficient. To my knowledge (although I cannot firmly confirm anymore, someone may prove me wrong), there is still a single instruction being executed at once, but different branches with different masks can now be interleaved in time. For a complex control flow, it may even happen that the same branch is executed multiple times, with different masks!

I remember speeding up my CUDA-based ray-tracer 2-3 times when I eliminated all `break` and mid-function `return` statements that were problematic for a compiler to figure out the optimal control flow and masking.

Comment: "Each single instruction in a warp is performed in a lockstep". Since the Volta architecture this is no longer valid. See [Independent Thread Scheduling](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/volta-tuning-guide/index.html#sm-independent-thread-scheduling)